# How to switch to the iframe as per the HTML provided through Selenium and Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, webdriver

This way I tried to switch to the frame:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//iframe[contains(@name,'vfFrameId')]//following::iframe[2]"))));
```

There are three iframes on the complete html code and I am trying to switch to the third one and I am able to the locate that as well using xpath but after running the script driver is not able to locate that and throwing an exception.

Exception:

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//iframe[contains(@name,'vfFrameId')]//following::iframe[2]"}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="windowViewMode-normal oneContent active forcePageHost" data-aura-rendered-by="1330:0" data-aura-class="forcePageHost">
    <div class="oneAlohaPage" data-aura-rendered-by="1335:0" data-aura-class="oneAlohaPage">
        <force-aloha-page data-data-rendering-service-uid="240" data-aura-rendered-by="1338:0" force-aloha-page_aloha-page="">
            <div class="slds-template_iframe slds-card" force-aloha-page_aloha-page="">
                <iframe height="100%" width="100%" scrolling="yes" allowtransparency="true" id="vfFrameId_1536141890078" name="vfFrameId_1536141890078" allowfullscreen="true" force-aloha-page_aloha-page="" allow="geolocation *; microphone *; camera *" title="Deploy Data Set"></iframe>
            </div>
        </force-aloha-page>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please share the stack trace of the exception thrown.

Comment: @Kshetra Mohan Prusty    no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//iframe[contains(@title,'Deploy Data Set')]"}

Comment: In this case, check if the frame is loaded before you try to locate it, meaning add an implicit wait to check the behavior of the page load.

Comment: If the iframes inside each other do you switch to each? Share you code

Comment: @Kshetra Mohan Prusty there is no problem related to page load, i have given 3 minutes wait time but still it is not getting located by driver

Comment: @Kshetra Mohan     so you can see the code above where you can see that there are three iframes available on the browser.  what happens that i click on one link then to interact with the elements i have to switch to the iframe and here i am able to switch but after clicking on an element ,i am getting navigated to the next page and there is another iframe introduced where i am not able to locate the iframe.@sers

Comment: @theGuy can you please provide the solution if possible

Comment: @Kshetra Mohanplease share the link of chatroom so i can explain in detail:

Comment: @AnuragShrivastava in html you provided `iframe`do element is empty. To help share full html throw text share url like https://justpaste.it/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the *text based HTML* and the *HTML* snapshot you have shared, it is not evident if there are multiple *iframes* available. So considering this `<iframe>` as a unique *iframe* you need to induce *WebDriverWait* while switching to the `<iframe>` as follows:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe[id^='vfFrameId_'][name^='vfFrameId_'][title='Deploy Data Set']")));
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@id,'vfFrameId_')][starts-with(@name,'vfFrameId_')][@title='Deploy Data Set']")));
  ```

Incase there are multiple *iframes* available with the same attributes which we have used above you can use the following solution:

- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//div[@class='windowViewMode-normal oneContent active forcePageHost' and @data-aura-class='forcePageHost']//following::iframe[1]")));
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can find the index of each iframe element

```
List <WebElement> options= driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
    for(WebElement e: options) {
        String index=e.getAttribute("index");
        System.out.println("Index for: "+e.getAttribute("name")+" is: "+index);// to print out name attribute and index
    }
```

If you are switching from iframe to iframe that don't work all the times. You may need to switch to default content from `iframe(1)` first and then switch to `iframe(2)`

```
driver.switchTo().frame(your locator for 1st iframe here);// to switch to 1st iframe
// your action here
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
driver.switchTo().frame(your locator for 2nd iframe here); // to switch to 2nd iframe
```

Comment: so i have tried this solution but this is not working

Comment: what is not working? finding index or switching the iframe?

Comment: switching the frame

Comment: switching the frame

Comment: are you trying to switch by index or any other method? Can you show me your code for this action?

Comment: driver.switchTo().frame(your locator for 1st iframe here);// to switch to 1st iframe
// your action here
thread.sleep(8000);
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
thread.sleep(8000);
driver.switchTo().frame(your locator for 2nd iframe here);
yes it got worked but when i put some wait time between the process. I mean while switching to default content and then switching to the next frame.

Comment: right, wait times are crucial when locating any element including iframe. I am glad it worked for you. Please accept this as an answer. Also, I would recommend to use implicit or Explicit wait times instead of Thread.sleep as you don't know if next element is going to take more or less than 8 secs to appear.

Answer (score 1):

I am working from your comment:

> so you can see the code above where you can see that there are three iframes available on the browser. what happens that i click on one link then to interact with the elements i have to switch to the iframe and here i am able to switch but after clicking on an element ,i am getting navigated to the next page and there is another iframe introduced where i am not able to locate the iframe

You need the following sequence of events:

1. Switch to your iframe. From this point, your `driver` instance is pointing at this iframe!
2. Click on the element that transitions to the next page.
3. Your `driver` instance is *still* pointing at the iframe from step 1! You need to reset it to the top document using: `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();`.
4. Only now can you switch to the new iframe on the page you just navigated to.